# Java Connect x game Minimax Algorithm

Tags: java, model-view-controller, minimax

I am trying to make a connect 4 game in which the user can select the dimensions of the board and how many pieces must be connected to win. (so we could have a 10 by 12 board in which we must connect 6 pieces for eg). I am using the MVC template for my code and am now trying to make an AI (in a separate ai class) which uses the minimax algorithm.

Right now my minimax algorithm sometimes removes my moves or replaces them with its own.
I think that this is because I don't make a copy of the board, I let the AI place and score a move and then i remove it. But I don't think that this works with recursion.

In my code, I use the following methods/parameters:

-"ourBoard" -> the game board (which i take from the model class)

-"connect" -> the amount of pieces needed in a row to win the game (usually 4)

-"counter" -> indicates who's turn it is. 1 for the player 2 for the ai

-"player" -> integer 1

-"ai" -> integer 2

-"depth" -> the depth of the minimax algorithm (how many moves ahead it sees)

-"maximizingPlayer" -> whether the player who's turn it is we want to maximise or minimise the score of

-"model" -> i need to use this as a parameter to get access to methods in the model class

-"nrCols" -> number of columns of the board

-"nrRows" -> number of rows of the board

-"validLocations" -> an array containing all the columns in which we can place a piece (ie those that arent full)

-"isTerminal" -> whether the game is ended or not

-"winner" -> checks if the player has won

My code is as follows:

```
public int[] minimax(int[][] ourBoard, int connect, int counter, int depth, boolean maximizingPlayer, Model model, int nrCols, int nrRows) {

        int[] validLocations = validLocations(ourBoard,nrCols);

        boolean isTerminal = isTerminalNode(ourBoard,connect,counter,model);
        //int[] result = new int[2];

        if (depth <= 0 || isTerminal) {

            if (isTerminal) {
               if (model.winner(connect, ai, ourBoard)) {
                    return new int[] {-1, (int) 100000000000000000L};
                }
                else if (model.winner(connect, player, ourBoard)) {
                    return new int[]{-1, (int) -100000000000000000L};
                }
                else {
                    return new int[] {-1, 0};
                }
            }
            else {
                return new int[] {-1,score(ai,ourBoard,connect,nrRows,nrCols)};
            }
        }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        if (maximizingPlayer) {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int rand = rnd.nextInt(validLocations.length);
            int column = validLocations[rand];

            int value = (int) -1000000000000000000L;
            for (int col = 0 ; col < validLocations.length ; col++) {
                int row = aiGetRow(validLocations[col], ourBoard, nrRows);
                ourBoard[row][col] = ai;
                int newScore = minimax(ourBoard,connect,counter,depth-1,false,model,nrCols,nrRows)[1];
                ourBoard[row][col] = 0;
                if (newScore > value) {
                    value = newScore;
                    column = col;
                }
            }
            return new int[]{column, value};
        }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        else { // not maximising player
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int rand = rnd.nextInt(validLocations.length);
            int column = validLocations[rand];

            int value = (int) 1000000000000000000L;
            for (int col = 0 ; col < validLocations.length ; col++) {
                int row = aiGetRow(validLocations[col], ourBoard, nrRows);
                ourBoard[row][col] = player;
                int newScore = minimax(ourBoard,connect,counter,depth-1,true,model,nrCols,nrRows)[1];
                ourBoard[row][col] = 0;
                if (newScore < value) {
                    value = newScore;
                    column = col;
                }
            }
            return new int[] {column,value};
        }

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: It's OK to make and undo the move in situ rather than making an entire copy of the board (and for efficiency, that's what you'd often do in this type of algorithm), provided that you reliably make a move in a valid place and then reliably undo it after each recursive call. So I would put some logging in to dump out the state of the board before and after moves to validate that it is behaving as you expect. Also, before making a move, I would add a simple check to make sure that the previous value in that square is indeed 0 as you are assuming..

Comment: As Neil said, this is the normal way of doing it: making a move, scoring it, and then remove the piece. Either you are calculating the validLocations wrong, or you place them wrong on the board afterwards. Print the valid locations along with the board and see if it looks okay.